# What happens if I overwrite a system-wide variable in a batch script on windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to batch scripting (for Windows), so I am reading a tutorial on it. The tutorial states

> WARNING: SET will always overwrite (clobber) any existing
>   variables. . It’s a good idea to verify you aren’t overwriting a system-wide variable when writing a script... For example, it might be tempting to name a variable
>   “temp”, but, that would change the meaning of the widely used “%TEMP%”
>   environmental variable.

However the tutorial does not go into the consequences of doing this.
What will happen if I write a batch file that simply overwrites one of these system-wide variables, will it only change the variable in the scope of the script? What about if I type it straight into the command line?

Normally I would just run it an see what happens, but I don't want to accidentally overwrite something important.

Comment: You mean batch scripting?

Comment: Are you talking about bash in WSL or general batch scripting in DOS?

Comment: @Kappa yep, guess so...like I said new to this :P. edited.

Comment: Hopefully he is not talking about DOS. Changes will be gone after the shell that runs the batch is closed.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I am not super familiar with the terminology. I would write a program in a text editor on Windows 10, with the extension .cmd and then run it from the Windows Command Prompt, cmd.exe

Comment: In the batch language (cmd.exe), you can create a local variable scope via `setlocal` and end it via `endlocal`. The end of a script has an implied `endlocal` for all outstanding `setlocal` scopes.

Comment: Yeah, that's regular batch. The changes will persist until you close the cmd window. If you start the script with `setlocal`, the changes will revert when either the script encounters an `endlocal` or it ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` only overwrites variables in that instance of cmd.exe (and child processes started from this instance), it does not affect other console windows (new or existing) and all these variable changes are lost when you close the console window.

You can also make `set` changes scoped to your batch file with `setlocal`:

```
@echo off
set global=Hello
setlocal
set private=world
```

Persistent changes can be made with the `setx` resource kit utility.

Comment: Please don't conflate cmd with the console. cmd is a shell, not a console or terminal. An instance of cmd has nothing inherently to do with console windows, other than that it defaults to inheriting the console of its parent or allocating a new one, just like how any console process works. You can run cmd.exe without a console (e.g. using piped standard I/O), and updating its environment has nothing to do with the environment variables in the console host process, conhost.exe.

Comment: @eryksun conhost is a implementation detail that only applies to Windows 7 and later, earlier versions used csrss.exe but these types of details are better left out when dealing with simple batch-file questions (IMHO).

Comment: Yes, conhost.exe is an implementation detail, but not the console itself. It has to be hosted somewhere, and that was never in cmd.exe or any shell or particular console client process. Changing environment variables in the cmd shell has nothing to do with console windows, and talking about how it "affect[s] other console windows" is only perpetuating a common misconception.

Comment: If I'm running cmd.exe as a detached process, with its standard handles directed to pipes and using a custom GUI terminal for the user interface, there is no console. Moreover, there may not even be a user interface if I'm running a batch script via cmd that's running detached in session 0. The console is not inherent to discussing cmd or the batch language, just as an xterm isn't inherent to discussing bash on Linux.